# Using Loop to Clear contents

Tags: vba, excel

I've written the following code to check if values in row A equal to "Forecast" then `Range D5:D53` should have its contents cleared.

Row 1 is a vlookup so there's a formula that derives "Actual" or "Forecast"

```
Dim k As Integer

For k = 1 To 13
    If Sheets("2017 Forecast").Cells(k, 1).Value = "Forecast" Then
        Sheets("2017 Forecast").Range("D5:D53").Select.ClearContents
    End If
Next k
```

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that the code errors out on line 3 i.e. it doesn't clear contents...

Comment: Just remove `.Select` - there is no reason to have that there - just use `Sheets("2017 Forecast").Range("D5:D53").ClearContents`

Comment: You mention "row A".  Do you mean column A, or row 1?  Your code (once you fix the error of the `Select`) is looking at column A.  Is that what you want?  If it isn't, that might explain why, when you change your code to just look at cell A4, it doesn't work - because you have the "Forecast" in cell D1.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `Select` before you use `ClearContents`.

Also, try adding `UCase` to make sure you don't have any CAPITAL letter in the middle of your text.

**Code**

```
Dim k As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2017 Forecast")
    For k = 1 To 13
        If UCase(.Cells(k, 1).Value2) = "FORECAST" Then
            .Range("D5:D53").ClearContents
        End If
    Next k
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you?

```
Option explicit

Sub Compare skies()

Dim k As long
Dim ValueRead as variant

With Sheets("2017 Forecast")
For k = 1 To 13

ValueRead = .Cells(k, 1).Value

' Slow, case insensitive string comparison '
If strcomp(ValueRead,"Forecast",vbtextcompare) = 0 Then
    .Range("D5:D53").ClearContents ' You want to clear the exact same range 13 times? '
Elseif strcomp(ValueRead,"Actual",vbtextcompare) <> 0 then
Msgbox("VLOOKUP returned a value outside of Actual and Forecast")

End if

Next k
End with

End sub
```